# Codimension of a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $X$ a vector space. Let $X_0 \subseteq X$ a vector subspace of $X$.

Suppose for a moment that $dim(X)=n$

Show: If $dim (X/X_0)=1$ then exists a linear functional $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $Kerf=X_0$

Of course is easy to think that if $dim (X/X_0)=1$ then exists a bijection $\ $$g:X/X_0 \to \mathbb{R}$ (linear?). We can use the quotient map and we are done.

**Can someone show me an explicit functional g with that properties?**

My idea is to think about a function which sends $[x] \to 0$ if $x \in X_0$ for all $y \in X$, and otherwise $[x] \to a$, for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ because all vectors that are not in $X_0$ should be of the form $ax$.

However I don't how to prove it is linear and even more a bijection.

Thank you very much.

Comment: it's $\phi(x) = \langle x, v  \rangle$ where $f(v) = 1$

Comment: Sure, what would be $g$??

Comment: Just pick a basis with $v$ belonging to it and, then, define $f(w) = $ the projection at the $v$ direction. Note that $v \notin X_0$

Comment: Please include this as comment, because I don't have enough points: I'm confused; every linear map into $R$--having dimension $1$ over itself, has a kernel of codimension $n-1$, so I don't see how the kernel can have dimension $1$, unless $V$ itself has dimension $2$. But maybe I misunderstood--or misunderestimated :) your question. EDIT: my answer was backwards: any non-zero linear functional into the base-field --as a vector space over itself-- has kernel of dimension $n-1$ by, e.g., Rank-Nullity theorem, by expressing the map as a linear map, after choosing a basis.

Comment: Do you mean a basis in $X/X_0$ and then use the projection in that direction? (Note that in this case, because is ℝ, the projection is a real number)

Comment: No, a basis in $X$. Defining the functional is equivalent to choosing a direction. If you want a $g$, just pick $g(\lambda v) = \lambda$

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Example: $X=\mathbb R_{n-1}[x]$ (polynomials with degré $\leq n-1$.   and  $X_0=x\mathbb R_{n-1}[x]={P \in X/ P(0)=0\}$.

if $\dim (X/X_0)=1$ let $a \in X \backslash X_0$, then $X=\mathbb R a \oplus X_0$. if  $x \in X$  there exist a unique  \lambda_x \in \mathbb R$  and $x_0 \in X_0$ such that $x=\lambda a + x_0$. Put $\phi(x)=\lambda_x$, then $\phi$ is linear map from $X$ to $\mathbb R$  and $\ker \phi= X_0$   so   $$X/X_0 \sim \mathbb R a  \sim  \mathbb R$$

Answer (score 0):

Take a basis $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{n-1}\}$ of $X_0$ and complete it to a basis of $X$ by simply taking a vector $v_n\in X$, $v_n\notin X_0$. Define
$$
f(v_i)=\begin{cases}
0 & 1\le i<n\\
1 & i=n
\end{cases}
$$
This is a linear functional with the requested properties.